# Strange caching issue with ansible and ssh proxy connection

Tags: ansible

I'm currently setting up two of [these](https://thepihut.com/cdn/shop/products/cluster-hat-v2-5-8086-mmp-1314-15516791799870_700x.jpg?v=1646604190) raspberry pi clusters. Basically a raspberry pi 4 with 4 attached raspberry pi zeros. The main pis are reachable simply with ssh by the hostnames `cluster-1` and `cluster-2`. The zeros are reachable from the main pi via natted addresses and hostnames `p1`, `p2`, .... and private IPs `172.19.180.1`, ... (these are the same hostnames and IPs on both `cluster-1`and `cluster-2`).

I've written ansible plays to configure both the main pis as well as the zeros. To reach the zeros, I'm using their corresponding main pi as a jump host. This is done with the ssh `ProxyCommand` option, which I define as a host variable in the inventory:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -A -W %h:%p -q {{ parent }}"'
```

As you can see I'm using a variable `parent`, which I use to control what cluster to setup (I'll need to setup some more of these). The variable is passed on the commandline of ansible like this:

```
ansible worker -e parent=cluster-1 -m shell -a "ls -l /tmp/"
ansible worker -e parent=cluster-2 -m shell -a "ls -l /tmp/"
```

All works fine except there's a strange caching error: After processing the zeros on `cluster-1` in the first call, the second call doesn't connect to `cluster-2` but again to `cluster-1`. This behavior is fixed by a brutal `rm -rf .ansible` between the calls:

```
ansible worker -e parent=cluster-1 -m shell -a "ls -l /tmp/"
rm -rf ~/.ansible
ansible worker -e parent=cluster-2 -m shell -a "ls -l /tmp/"
```

Removing the ansible directory between calls makes everything work as expected and I assume something is cached in there to cause this behavior.

So here my question: **How do I prevent this caching behavior**?

I already configured ansible to only use the memory cache with a timeout of 1s, but none of the caching options seem to have any influence on the behavior. My `ansible.cfg` is really mininmal, my `.ssh/config` is empty on all involved hosts, and I'm running ansible on a vanilla debian bullseye.

For completeness my ansible setup:

- My `ansible.cfg` file

  ```
  [defaults]
  log_path=./ansible.log
  host_key_checking=False
  inventory=./inventory/main.yaml
  fact_caching=memory
  fact_caching_timeout=1
  transport=ssh
  [inventory]
  cache=False
  cache_timeout=1
  enable_plugins=yaml
  ```
- My `inventory/main.yaml` file:

  ```
  worker:
    hosts:
      p1:
      p2:
      p3:
      p4:
    vars:
      ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -A -W %h:%p -q {{ parent }}"'
  ```